# How to configure linaro-gcc

Tags: eclipse, gcc, linaro

Now i'm using gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf and using eclipse to cross-compile. But when build, i get error like

```
home/osboxes/artik5/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/osboxes/artik5/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/osboxes/artik5/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
makefile:209: recipe for target 'hc' failed
/home/osboxes/artik5/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

Anyone help me fix this bug. I find crt1.o, crti.o, libpthread.so.0 and libpthread_nonshared.a in `/home/osboxes/artik5/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/li`b

Answer (score 0):

rt1.o, crti.o and crtn.o and libc.a all come with your glibc.
you need use  `--sysroot` option to tell gcc where to search for binaries created by glibc.

Comment: They actually come with linaro gcc in libc folder so setting the correct sysroot breaks them ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯